# How to disable back screen when kendo window is open

Tags: kendo-ui, grid, window

I create on kendo window dialog box, how can i disable background screen when kendo window is open. means when kendo window is open user can't do anything.

Comment: For Window: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/window/configuration/modal or for dialog: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/dialog/configuration/modal

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#dialog").kendoWindow({
  modal: false
});
```